# GCP 0auth2 playground service account

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, cypress

I try to get access token via my given service account json data.
I can have it only on REST request (js).

On 0auth2 playground I don't understand if it is possible to use service account data to get the access token. There is no client secret to give it.

I try to use REST request to get access token. Cypress for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get an OAuth Access Token from a service account by **only** making REST API calls. The process requires creating a JWT, signing the JWT with the private key, and exchanging the signed JWT for an access token.